# Error log is displayed in console for log4j2 after using LoggerContext

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using LoggerContext to set log4j2,xml path in code and getting No log4j2 configuration file found error log.

**Code**

```
    LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
    String  fileName = "\\resources\\log4j2.xml";
    context.setConfigLocation(new File(fileName).toURI());
    LOG.debug("This Will Be Printed On Debug");
    LOG.info("This Will Be Printed On Info");
    LOG.warn("This Will Be Printed On Warn");
```

**Output**

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only 
errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to 
TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
DEBUG | 2020-06-19 14:16:21 | [main] | (Log4j2Example.java:22) - This Will Be Printed On Debug
INFO  | 2020-06-19 14:16:21 | [main] | (Log4j2Example.java:23) - This Will Be Printed On Info
WARN  | 2020-06-19 14:16:21 | [main] | (Log4j2Example.java:24) - This Will Be Printed On Warn
```

Here I am getting expected result but also getting error log at start. 
If I set log4j2,xml in classpath in eclipse then no error is displayed.

How can we remove error log while using LoggerContext?

Comment: I'm not really sure if that fixes your problem, because I didn't really look into it, but i think you seem to be missing a "(" before org.apache.logging ...

Comment: @maloomeister typo mistake.  I have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

When you call LogManager.getContext(false) Log4j is going to initialize. This causes the No log4j2 configuration file found message because you haven't configured one yet.

Try using `Configurator.initialize("My Config", "\\resources\\log4j2.xml");`